# Rxjs wait for response and run method again

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have code, that checking status and if status is not `Completed` or `Failed`, retry call

Here is code

```
    getRecognitionById() {
    this.loaderService.show(null, true);
    this.vendorWebApiService
      .createRecognition(this.executiveChangeId)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.refresher$ = interval(5000);
        this.refreshSub = this.refresher$.subscribe(() => {
          this.checkStatus(res.taskRequestId);
          if (this.jobStatus === "Completed") {
            this.refreshSub.unsubscribe();
            this.getLatestFeedback();
            this.loaderService.hide(true);
          }
          if (this.jobStatus === "Failed") {
            this.loaderService.hide(true);
            this.refreshSub.unsubscribe();
            alert("Recognition failed. Try again later");
          } else {
            if (this.checkCount < 36) {
              this.checkStatus(res.taskRequestId); //run check status again only when we get response
            } else {
              this.loaderService.hide(true);
              this.refreshSub.unsubscribe();
              alert("Recognition failed. Try again later");
            }
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

I need to wait for response from `checkStatus()` method and only then run `checkStatus()` again (I commented part of code where I need to achieve this logic)

Here is code of `checkStatus` method

```
 checkStatus(taskRequestId: number) {
    this.checkCount++;
    this.vendorWebApiService
      .getRecognition(taskRequestId, this.executiveChangeId)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((recognitionResponse) => {
        this.jobStatus = recognitionResponse.jobStatus;
        if (recognitionResponse.jobStatus === "Completed") {
          this.recognitionData = recognitionResponse;
        }
      });
  }
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: its good to use rxjs pipe operator like switchMap() here.

Comment: Can you show how and where I need to use it? @GaurangDhorda

Comment: first make this code demo using stackblitz so that it will be more helpful to understand it

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of extra bits in your code, so I doubt this would compile as-is. Even so, here's an idea for something that should work if you iron out the kinks.

```ts
// By returning an observable that emits once the status is checked,
// we use emission to know when the status is checked.
checkStatus(taskRequestId: number): Observable<Status> {

  return this.vendorWebApiService.getRecognition(
    taskRequestId, 
    this.executiveChangeId
  ).pipe(

      take(1),

      /* This info is emitted directly into your stream now, so
      // you shouldn't need to se global variables here anymore.
      // uncomment this to get those gloabls being set again.
      // Up to you. 
      tap(recognitionResponse => {
        this.jobStatus = recognitionResponse.jobStatus;
        if (recognitionResponse.jobStatus === "Completed") {
          this.recognitionData = recognitionResponse;
        }
      })
      */
  );

}

getRecognitionById() {

  this.loaderService.show(null, true);

  this.vendorWebApiService.createRecognition(this.executiveChangeId).pipe(

    switchMap(res => this.checkStatus(res.taskRequestId).pipe(

      tap(({jobStatus}) => {
        if (jobStatus !== "Completed" && jobStatus !== "Failed") {
          throw "This is an error we can catch and retry with";
        }
      }),

      // If there's an error try again
      retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
        take(36), // Retry a max of 36 times
        s => concat(s, defer(() => {
          // After 36 retry attempts, we still failed
          this.loaderService.hide(true);
          alert("Recognition failed. Try again later");
          return EMPTY;
        })),
        delay(5000) // Wait 5 seconds before retry
      ))
    )),

    take(1)

  ).subscribe(recognitionResponse => {

    const {jobStatus} = recognitionResponse;

    if (jobStatus === "Completed") {
      this.recognitionData = recognitionResponse;
      this.getLatestFeedback();
    }

    if (jobStatus === "Failed") {
      alert("Recognition failed. Try again later");
    }

    this.loaderService.hide(true);

  });
}
```